# initialize vector of pointers (automatically)

Tags: c++, pointers, null, stdvector

I encountered a compilation error when trying to initialize a vector of pointers to `NULL` by way of the `std::vector` constructor. I simplify the instruction to keep it simple:

```
vector<int*> v (100,NULL)
```

I guess it has something to do with an incompatibility between `const T& value= T()` (the parameter of the constructor) and the very value NULL, but I would appreciate some further explanation.

Thank you

Comment: An "execution error"?  What is the error?  Did you run this in the debugger to confirm it was this line that was failing?

Comment: No, I didn't use a debugger (i'm kind of a newbie).
Also, it's not an execution but a compilation error, i was mistaken.
Here you go:

ArbreN.hpp:55:3: warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 2 of ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = int, _Tp = ArbreNari<int>::node_arbreNari*, _Alloc = std::allocator<ArbreNari<int>::node_arbreNari*>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<ArbreNari<int>::node_arbreNari*>]’ [-Wconversion-null]

Comment: By the way, if you use the one-argument constructor (`vector<int *> v(100);`, they will automatically be initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the warning on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/jneCt)).

Comment: When asking about a particular piece of code that does not compile, make sure to include the compiler error message. Complex as they are sometimes, they usually include important information that can help determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: If you can (i.e. if are using C++11, which you should unless you have a *very good reason* not to), use `nullptr`.

Comment: what compiler are you using? I cannot reproduce the problem with GCC.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If pointers are set to NULL by default then I don't see the point of doing what I intended to. Anyway, I was curious of how the language treats the NULL value compared to other 'templatizatable' types. I'm using GCC (though I don't know how to find out which version) by g++ -c main.cpp. That's where I get the error (even with the simplified instruction I wrote on the post).

Answer (score 6):

If you have the relevant C++11 support, you could use `nullptr`:

```
std::vector<int*> v(100, nullptr);
```

However, in your particular case, there is no need to specify a default value, so the following would suffice:

```
std::vector<int*> v(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is likely defined as `0`, so you end up with

```
vector<int*> v(100,0);
```

which tries to build a vector of `int`s, not of `int*`s.

Just skip the NULL, as that is default for pointers anyway, or cast it to the correct pointer type `(int*)NULL`.

Comment: I guess it is rather trying to use the constructor overload taking two input iterators (by resolving the input iterator type to be `int`). It doesn't just magically try to create a vector of `int`s, it's still a `std::vector<int*>` constructor that is called.

Comment: Well, that's my way of looking at it.  :-) The main problem is that NULL is a 0, which makes the constructor call look like `vector(int,int)`. That *would* have worked for a `vector<int>`.