# Initialize pointers in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, initialization

I am trying to initialize all pointers in vector to NULL.
Based on thread:
[initialize vector of pointers (automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960508/initialize-vector-of-pointers-automatically)
and 
[How to initialize a vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090680/how-to-initialize-a-vector-of-pointers)

I could just use the vector constructor to achieve what I want. My question is : is the initialization NULL pointer is a standard behaviour? Or the pointers in vector might not be NULL on some compiler?
If initialize to NULL is standard, could anyone tell me in which chapter and section can I find the related info from c++ standard?

Thanks,

Rong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean something like this:

```
std::vector<MyClass*> v(10);
```

Yes, the vector is initialized with null pointers.  Quoting the standard by chapter and verse is somewhat involved…

C++14 §23.3.6.2 “`vector constructors, copy, and assignment”:

> `explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator());`
>
> *Effects:* Constructs a `vector` with `n` default-inserted elements using the specified allocator.
>
> *Requires:* `T` shall be `DefaultInsertable` into `*this`.

§23.2.1 “General container requirements” ¶13:

> — `T` is *`DefaultInsertable`* into `X` means that the following expression is well-formed:
>
> ```
> allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)
> ```
>
> — An element of `X` is *default-inserted* if it is initialized by evaluation of the expression
>
> ```
> allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)
> ```
>
> where `p` is the address of the uninitialized storage for the element allocated within `X`.

§20.7.8.2 “Allocator traits member functions” ¶5:

> ```
> template <class T, class... Args>
>   static void construct(Alloc& a, T* p, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* calls `a.construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` if that call is well-formed; otherwise, invokes `::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`.

§20.7.9.1 “[Default] `allocator` members” ¶12:

> ```
> template <class U, class... Args>
>   void construct(U* p, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* `::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

Referring back to §23.2.1 ¶13, see that `args` is empty.  Therefore…

§8.5 “Initializers”:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., `()`, shall be value-initialized.

Same section:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means: … otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Same section:

> To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type `T` means: … if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal `0` (zero) to `T`;<sup>106</sup>

Footnote 106:

> As specified in 4.10, converting an integer literal whose value is `0` to a pointer type results in a null pointer value.